# Define exotic operations so that $\mathbb R^2$ has a $1$ dimensional basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am working on an exercise from *Linear Algebra with Applications 5ed by Otto Bretscher*. The problem is: Can we define "exotic" operations on $\mathbb R^2$ so that its dimension is $1$. This seems impossible but the solution manual says it it possible. They say to let $T$ be an invertible function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. Then they use the existence of such a transformation to define exotic operations based off of that function and its inverse. Before I even try to understand the second part of their solution, I do not understand why we can just say that such an invertible transformation $T$ exists between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$. I can't even think of an example of such a transformation.

Comment: It's a result from set theory ("cardinality" is the concept to read up on, if you're curious) that such a transformation exists. But any such map will have to be "messy", in ways that can be made mathematically precise. Lorago gives about as nice an example as possible below. It's nice to understand it, but it's probably not necessary for the rest of the text, so I would suggest not spending too much time worrying if it's not totally clear.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. This will increase your chances of getting help in this forum.

Comment: what happened to the answer by @lorago , it disappeared

Comment: lorago deleted his/her own answer after the observations I did of the answer been incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Bijections $T : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ exist but are annoying to write down and poorly behaved. The argument that they exist is usually done more indirectly using the [Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). The CBS theorem says that if $A, B$ are two sets and you can find an injection $f : A \hookrightarrow B$ and an injection $g : B \hookrightarrow A$, then you can find a bijection $h : A \cong B$, so $A$ and $B$ have the same [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality); this is done by weaving together $f$ and $g$ in a specific way.

The CBS can be used to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as the set $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ of infinite binary strings. This is slightly annoying but can be done as follows: given an infinite binary string $a_i \in \{ 0, 1 \}, i \in \mathbb{N}$ we can write down a real number with binary expansion $0.a_1 0 a_2 0 a_3 0 \dots $ (the $0$s here are to avoid an annoying issue with identities like $0.0111 \dots = 0.1$). This gives an injection $2^{\mathbb{N}} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In the other direction, given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can first consider $\arctan x$, which lives in the interval $\left( - \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ (this is a bijection and a very well-behaved one), then shift it around a bit to live in the open interval $(0, 1)$, for example via

$$\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto \frac{\arctan x}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \in (0, 1).$$

Next we can consider the binary expansion $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 \dots $  of this number, which produces an infinite binary string. This is an injection $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ (almost but not quite a bijection, again because of identities like $0.0111 \dots = 0.1$). So by the CBS theorem we have a bijection $h : \mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

(This is a *very* annoying argument as you can see but you only need to do it once and then you know forever that $\mathbb{R}$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality. A mathematician will immediately substitute one for the other in a cardinality argument without blinking.)

Now instead of finding a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ we'll find a bijection $2^{\mathbb{N}} \to (2^{\mathbb{N}})^2$. This is now easy: $(2^{\mathbb{N}})^2 \cong 2^{\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}}$ is the set of pairs of infinite binary strings, and so a bijection is given by interweaving:

$$2^{\mathbb{N}} \ni (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots) \mapsto (a_1, a_3, a_5, \dots), (a_2, a_4, a_6, \dots) \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \times 2^{\mathbb{N}}.$$

This gives us a bijection $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ by first applying our CBS bijection $h : \mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, then interweaving, then applying two copies of the inverse bijection $h^{-1} : 2^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathbb{R}$. Like I said: annoying to write down! It's much faster to not even try to write down a bijection and just argue about the equivalence relation "has the same cardinality." Once you have some sense of how this works the argument can be blazed through like this:

$$\mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}} \cong (2^{\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}}) \cong (2^{\mathbb{N}})^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2.$$

Comment: Thank you for showing what "messy" means.